# How to compare variables in a list (number chars in order from 1 to n without changing the position of the chars in a list)

Tags: list, python-3.x, comparison

In short i  want to number chars in order from 1 to n without changing the position of the chars in a list.

Suppose I have a list called key = ['c', 'a', 't'] How would i go about
assigning a number to each letter depending on where it is situated in the alphabet with respect to the other letters. Starting at 1 and going until len(key) such that our key becomes [ 2, 1, 3]

I'm really stumped. I have a way to convert them to numbers but very unsure as to how to compare them such that the above happens any help, tips, ideas or explanations would be appreciated.

this is what i have so far...

```
import string

key = list(input("enter key: ").upper())
num = []
for i in key:
    num.append(string.ascii_uppercase.index(i)+1)
```

Comment: What if there are duplicates in the list, like what result do you want for ['c', 'a', 't', 'a', 'c']?

Comment: Thats a very good point, they should be identical so in your example [2,1,3,1,2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution assumes that duplicate entries should be assigned the same number, so that

```
# ['c','a','t'] -> [2, 1, 3]
# ['c','a','t','c','a','t'] -> [2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3]
```

You can write a simple function like this:

```
def get_alphabet_pos(lst):
    uniques = sorted(set(lst))  # set() to filter uniques, then order by value
    numbers = {letter: i+1 for i, letter in enumerate(uniques)}  # build a lookup dict
    return [numbers[key] for key in lst]

get_alphabet_pos('cat')  # [2, 1, 3]
```

So here's what happens in the function:

1. In line 1 of the function we convert your list to a set to remove any duplicate values. From the docs @ https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets:

> A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements.

2. Still in line 1 we sort the set and convert it back into a list. Thanks to @StefanPochmann for pointing out that `sorted()` takes care of the list conversion.
3. In line 2, we use `enumerate()` so we can iterate over the indices *and* values of our list of unique values: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate
4. The rest of line 2 is a simple dict comprehension to build a dictionary of `letter -> number` mappings. We use the dictionary in line 3 to look up the numbers for each letter in our input dict.

You might have to modify this slightly depending on how you want to handle duplicates :)

Comment: Brilliant i'm not acquainted with using set() or enumerate(). I will  look into those and try to understand what's going on here. In the meantime the program is working so thank you greatly

Comment: @StefanPochmann sets are unordered collections, though it seems like sorted(set(...)) does the list conversion automatically. I'll fix that in the answer. As for the variable `cat`, it was supposed to be a string :)

Comment: @Dead_Ling0 I added some explanation.